# How can i add html fragment using json in Django?

Tags: javascript, html, json, django

I get data which should render to page per item from json, such as

```
"Item1" : { name: bla,
age: bla, height: bla }, 
"Item2" : { name: bla,
age: bla, height: bla }, 
"Item3" : { name: bla,
age: bla, height: bla }.
```

So, I made javascripts

```
function appendList(ajaxCardsData) {
    for (var loop in ajaxCardsData) {
        var str = "<li class='node'>test</li>";
        $("ul.toappend").append(str);
    }
}
```

The thing is, var str is too long.(above sample is just for test.) Can I use the other way to add html fragments in javascript in Django?? like using {% include %} or templatetags?

How about using templatetags functioning loads template using from django.template import loaders? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try Angular js

javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['Controllers'])
.config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('$$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$$');
});
var Controllers = angular.module('Controllers',[]);
Controllers.controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope){
 $scope.data = ajaxCardsData;
}]);
```

html

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller = "myController">
    <ul ng-repeat="item in data">
      <li>$$item$$<li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```